# onBackPressed() in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have a three Fragments in a single activity, the FragmentTransaction for

Fragment A to Fragments B,
Fragment B to Fragment C

is working fine, but on onBackPressed() it will flow like

Fragment C to Fragment B, Fragment B to Fragment A,

But When onBackPressed() For Fragment A it will close the Fragment, I don't want to close Fragment A, here is my code.

On OnNavigationItemSelectedListener.

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
                transaction.commit();

                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_my_orders:
                fragment = new MyOrdersFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
              return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

For Loading Fragment.

```
 private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    // load fragment
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_enter, R.anim.right_enter);
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

How to solve please let me know.

Comment: why don't use `transaction.addToBackStack("");`

Comment: #Farrokh, if i don't use that transaction.addToBackStack(""); still it will close the Fragment A.

Answer (score 1):

Please add code in your activity.

```
   override fun onBackPressed() {
            if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0)
                supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
            else {
           }
        }
```

For loading Fragment

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_enter, R.anim.right_enter);
    transaction.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().toString());
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Or you can use the below code get the current fragment and check if it is intanceof FragemntA or not.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(getContainer())
        if(fragment !is FragmentA){
            supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The onBackPressed method is handle by the Activity who contains your fragments.

Inside your Activity you need to override the onBackPressed method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

The super.onBackPressed will remove your fragment you can add a condition for don't trigger it if you are in FragmentA

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     if (!isFragmentA){
         super.onBackPressed();
     }

}
```

You have several way to find  which fragment is currently display on screen.